# Error E3244: template constraint not satisfied

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2022

With some recent update of Visual Studio 2022 (now I have 17.7.4) I start getting the following error:

> Error E3244   template constraint not satisfied

for the following minumum reproducible example:

```cpp
#include <ranges>

int main()
{
}
```

when the `Configuration Properties->General->C++ Language Standard` is set to *Preview - Features from the Latest C++ Working Draft (/std:c++latest)*.

So, it is enough just to include `<ranges>` header file.

I assume it comes from IntelliSense since it comes to “Error List” window when I open the solution, without any compilation. No compilations errors or warnings come.

First error refers to *…VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\include\ranges    265*

```
template <_Valid_movable_box_object _Ty>
class _Movable_box {
public:
```

and says:

> type constraint failed for "std::tuple<>" atomic constraint evaluates
> to false
> detected during:
> instantiation of class "std::ranges::_Movable_box<_Ty> [with _Ty=std::tuple<>]" at line 1003
> instantiation of class "std::ranges::single_view<_Ty> [with _Ty=std::tuple<>]" at line 10105

and the second one refers to *…VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\include\tuple  248*

```
template <class _Tag, enable_if_t<is_same_v<_Tag, _STD _Exact_args_t>, int> = 0>
constexpr tuple(_Tag) noexcept /* strengthened */ {}
```

and says:

> type constraint failed for "std::tuple<>" atomic constraint evaluates
> to false
> detected during:
> instantiation of class "std::ranges::_Movable_box<_Ty> [with _Ty=std::tuple<>]" at line 1003 of
> "…\14.37.32822\include\ranges"
> instantiation of class "std::ranges::single_view<_Ty> [with _Ty=std::tuple<>]" at line 10105 of
> "…\14.37.32822\include\ranges"

Comment: When you compile your code, which file fails to compile? simply running compilation from VS should open the compiler output window and start compiling. When you figure out which file it is, look through it to see if intelliense marks something. If nothing but still fails to compile, start removing stuff until you find what fails to compile.
Without a minimal reproduction/example of what fails to compile, we can't help you.

Comment: @shakedcohen, as I stated in my question, no files fail to compile. This comes when I just open the solution. I can't remove stuff since the project is really large and it will take days to cut pieces and find the cause without any clue where to start cutting.

Comment: Sometimes intellisense and the compiler disagree. If you can compile, Intellisense is wrong, case solved. if you *cannot* compile, the output window will give you more detailed information about the instantiation location etc. which is extremely valuable.

Comment: @DamirTenishev sounds like intellisense has a bug, although it is not unheard of that intelliense was right and msvc compiled code that it shouldn't. I somewhat agree with Peter here - if it compiles, generally forget about it.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica, my idea was to find somebody with the same error or somebody who knows this part of code better and could give a hint what usage could cause the error or confirm that this is known VS issue. Meanwhile, if Intellisense is wrong, how could I suppress warnings for these two specific lines so that I have my Error List clear and can see other errors and warning while they can?

Comment: @shakedcohen, risky... but I would agree so far. The only way to forget is to get rid of it from Error List since I have "zero warnings tolerance" (funny to suppress, then, but anyway). Is there a way to suppress not a type of error, but the error message for specific lines of systems files which I couldn't change?

Comment: I must admit that I didn't understand that this has come up after a VS update, presumably without a code change. So it continues to compile? -- Btw, I am not sure whether  you can suppress errors in Intelisense. YOu can suppress warnings in general (and I think Intellisense honors those settings), but errors? That would not make sense, normally. But I'd have to google that as much as you do.

Comment: In any case, if this is a false positive after an upgrade it is worth a formal bug report. If you are a using a payed-for edition you are also entitled to support, I believe.

Comment: @DamirTenishev I generally agree with the "zero warning tolerance" policy, but sometimes things are out of our hands. If you don't want to ignore it, you can rollback to 17.7.3 and wait it out.
I don't know of a way to suppress specific instances of errors. If we knew which line the error came from then maybe.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica, yes it continues to compile without any warnings from compiler and yes, it came without any change in code, just with the VS upgrade to 17.7.2, 17.7.3 or 17.7.4 - I can't remember the exact version when I got this.

Comment: @DamirTenishev A bug then. File a report, get support.

Comment: Any updates? You can post the bug report link in the comments. And it will be better to provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT, please read the last paragraph of my question. I have no any clue what file or line of code causes this, since this comes from IntelliSense without any reference to my code. The issue is happening only in one project which is quite lager to cut the pieces. This it in my way both to create a bug report and to create minimal reproducible example. If you know any way to learn from IntelliSense the causing code or at least file, please share so that I could narrow the range.

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT, I found the minimal reproducible example, please see the updated post. It is enough to include '<ranges>' header file. Can you please check if you have the same issue on your environment?

Comment: @shakedcohen, I found the minimal reproducible example, please see the updated post. It is enough to include '<ranges>' header file. Can you please check if you have the same issue on your environment?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it with the following version: Using VS Community Edition 17.8 (Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022
Version 17.8.0
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.8.0+34309.116

Installed Version: Community

Visual C++ 2022   00482-90000-00000-AA378
Microsoft Visual C++ 2022

Comment: By the way, the error window gives you the option to show only errors from compilation, only from Intellisense, or from both. That way you can tell for sure.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica, thank you both for the feedback and the hint; the latter made my day. Now I can have error window clean this way until this resolves.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica, do you have /std:c++latest option included? Can you please check with it, if no. Another request, please try with the "Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Language > Enable C++ Modules (experimental)" turned on.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica, I just changed `/std:c++latest` to `/std:c++20` and the issue has disappeared (see the details in the updated question). Is seems this is in the latest preview mode only.